# When I use the kill -9 command to kill the pengine process, the DRBD resource cannot switch anymore. What is the reason for this?

Tags: pacemaker

When I use the kill -9 command to kill the pengine process, the DRBD resource cannot switch anymore. What is the reason for this?

```
goldwind-single(dataprocess)[17309]:    2023/06/29_14:21:27 INFO: 【goldwind-app】:run dataprocess -【stop】
Jun 29 14:21:27 [8281] node116       crmd:     info: match_graph_event: Action dataprocess_sync_notify_0 (245) confirmed on node114 (rc=0)
Jun 29 14:21:27 [8278] node116       lrmd:     info: log_finished:      finished - rsc:dataprocess_sync action:notify call_id:455 pid:17310 exit-code:0 exec-time:49ms queue-time:0ms
Jun 29 14:21:27 [8281] node116       crmd:     info: match_graph_event: Action dataprocess_sync_notify_0 (247) confirmed on node116 (rc=0)
Jun 29 14:21:27 [8281] node116       crmd:   notice: process_lrm_event: Result of notify operation for dataprocess_sync on node116: 0 (ok) | call=455 key=dataprocess_sync_notify_0 confirmed=true cib-update=0
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_process_request:       Completed cib_delete operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=node114/crm_resource/3, version=0.866.2)
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    Diff: --- 0.866.2 2
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    Diff: +++ 0.867.0 (null)
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    +  /cib:  @epoch=867, @num_updates=0
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++ /cib/configuration/constraints:  <rsc_location id="cli-prefer-dataprocess_sync-master" rsc="dataprocess_sync-master" role="Master"/>
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                    <rule id="cli-prefer-rule-dataprocess_sync-master" score="INFINITY" boolean-op="and">
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                      <expression id="cli-prefer-expr-dataprocess_sync-master" attribute="#uname" operation="eq" value="node114" type="string"/>
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                      <date_expression id="cli-prefer-lifetime-end-dataprocess_sync-master" operation="lt" end="2023-06-29 06:21:33Z"/>
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                    </rule>
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                  </rsc_location>
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_process_request:       Completed cib_modify operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=node114/crm_resource/4, version=0.867.0)
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8281] node116       crmd:   notice: abort_transition_graph:    Transition aborted by rsc_location.cli-prefer-dataprocess_sync-master 'create': Configuration change | cib=0.867.0 source=te_update_diff_v2:511 path=/cib/configuration/constraints complete=false
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_backup:   Archived previous version as /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib-88.raw
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:        Wrote version 0.867.0 of the CIB to disk (digest: 5e1bc76740b1241f2e33f480a8148dd7)
Jun 29 14:21:31 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:        Reading cluster configuration file /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.MsStXI (digest: /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.uxUdCZ)
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_process_request:       Completed cib_delete operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=node114/crm_resource/3, version=0.867.0)
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    Diff: --- 0.867.0 2
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    Diff: +++ 0.868.0 (null)
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    +  /cib:  @epoch=868
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++ /cib/configuration/constraints:  <rsc_location id="cli-prefer-dataprocess_file_system" rsc="dataprocess_file_system" role="Started"/>
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                    <rule id="cli-prefer-rule-dataprocess_file_system" score="INFINITY" boolean-op="and">
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                      <expression id="cli-prefer-expr-dataprocess_file_system" attribute="#uname" operation="eq" value="node114" type="string"/>
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                      <date_expression id="cli-prefer-lifetime-end-dataprocess_file_system" operation="lt" end="2023-06-29 06:21:36Z"/>
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                    </rule>
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:    ++                                  </rsc_location>
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_process_request:       Completed cib_modify operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=node114/crm_resource/4, version=0.868.0)
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8281] node116       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:    Transition aborted by rsc_location.cli-prefer-dataprocess_file_system 'create': Configuration change | cib=0.868.0 source=te_update_diff_v2:511 path=/cib/configuration/constraints complete=false
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_backup:   Archived previous version as /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib-89.raw
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:        Wrote version 0.868.0 of the CIB to disk (digest: 4ee0b0b53a098f298b424bdb95c6d47f)
Jun 29 14:21:34 [8276] node116        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:        Reading cluster configuration file /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.VTfBxe (digest: /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.wvQ0bC)
goldwind-single(dataprocess)[17309]:    2023/06/29_14:21:37 INFO: 【goldwind-app】:run dataprocess -【stop】finish
```

This is log